# Replacing x-axis with data name on a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

There are three data points in column vector `SP` that I am trying to plot. Since I am new to MatLab, I still face following issue with plotting:

**Problem 1:** How do I replace X-axis with the name of each data point?

**Problem 2:** How do I add the value of each data point on the top of every point on the plot?

**Note:** From a reply to my previous question, I entered the name of each data point as a cell array (not as a character), but that does not work.

**This is my code:**

```
SP = [4.3376 4.4005 5.0925];
plot(SP,'-o');
title('SP and YP monthly returns');
xlabel('Monthly time series');
axis([0 4 0 7]);
labelCell = {'' '' 'Asset1' '' 'Asset2' '' 'Asset3' ''};
set(gca, 'xTickLabel', cellstr(MMM));
ylabel('Sharpe Ratio');
```

**My output in MatLab:**

[image]

**My desired output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It isn't working because you aren't using the correct variable when you are setting the `XTickLabels`. You are using `MMM`. Instead, it should be:

   ```
   labelCell = {'' '' 'Asset1' '' 'Asset2' '' 'Asset3' ''};
   set(gca, 'xTickLabel', labelCell);
   ```

   A better option that would allow you to not have to create the `''` labels would be to manually specify the `XTick` locations as well

   ```
   set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(SP), 'XTickLabel', {'Asset1', 'Asset2', 'Asset3'})
   ```
2. You can add `text` objects to your plot to place the labels above your data

   ```
   for k = 1:numel(SP)
       text(k, SP(k), {num2str(SP(k)), ''}, ...
           'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
           'verticalalignment', 'bottom')
   end
   ```

   Note that for the `String`, I use a cell array with an empty second element. This inserts an empty line between the label and the datapoint rather than manually having to compute the y value.